# Como parar um for via interferência externa do laço?

Tags: java, android

Tenho um `for` executando e ao clicar no botão quero que esse `for` pare.

```
           for (int i = 0; i < codigo.size(); i++) {


            if (codigo.get(i).contains("Para") || Stop == true){

                sendCommand("parou");

                break;

            } else {
                sendCommand(codigo.get(i));

            }
```

Estou mando valor tipo `String` quando ele acha a palavra "Para" ele sai do `for`, coloquei um tipo `boolean Stop` quando verdadeiro ele sairia do laço também, eu altero o valor apertando um botão mas não funcionou.
Gostaria de como pode pudesse sair `for` via um botão ou se teria outro meio de fazer isso.

Comment: Você quer que, por exemplo, se uma condição for falsa saia do loop?

Comment: Não seria o caso de usar o comando `break`?

Comment: No titulo da sua pergunta diz uma coisa e no corpo diz outra. Sugiro você deixa-la mais clara.

Comment: Não tem como parar a execução de um ciclo `for` no clique de um botão. Isso porque a interrupção teria de ser feita dentro do `for`. E o onClick do botão geralmente fica fora do ciclo... Talvez fosse melhor se você dissesse o que está querendo fazer. Para quê serve o ciclo?

Comment: Deixa eu adivinhar, a thread que está executando esse `for` é a mesma que deveria perceber o clique do botão. Acertei? Porque se for isso, você teria que ter uma mesma thread executando duas linhas de execução simultaneamente, o que não dá para fazer vez que uma thread é por definição, uma linha de execução. A solução seria rodar esse seu `for` dentro de uma thread separada.

Comment: @VictorStafusa tinha pensado nisso mas não tinha testado, testei como  uma nova thread e deu certo, valeu.

Answer (score 1):

```
   boolean keepGoing = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < codigo.size(); i++) {
        if (keepGoing) {
            i++;

        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

    void onClick(view v){
        keepGoing = false;
    }
```